# How to fix "AskSdk.GenericRequestDispatcher Error: Unable to find a suitable request handler" error in alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create a basic online radio streaming Alexa skill. I have written the code and deployed it in the AWS. Everything looks good but I am seeing an error as shown below in the logs when I try to open the skill.

AskSdk.GenericRequestDispatcher Error:

Unable to find a suitable request handler.
at Object.createAskSdkError (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/util/AskSdkUtils.js:22:17)
at GenericRequestDispatcher. (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/GenericRequestDispatcher.js:145:49).....
......
.....

Here is the link to the amazon developer forum where I posted the question in detail: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/212539/asksdkgenericrequestdispatcher-error-unable-to-fin.html.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,
Dev

Comment: Just deployed your skill and it is working as it should.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Romanenko, which device you have tested it on? I tried to test it on echo dot(probably 1st/2nd gen) and was getting that error. I have been stuck at this issue from past few days. Did you make any changes to the code at all? Thanks.

Comment: i just deployed it in my environment using Alexa Hosted variant and did the tests in web version.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Romanenko, Thank you for your response. I will try to deploy it again and see.